# Boolean value not assignable in xquery

Tags: xquery

```
let $my_val as xs:boolean := fn:true
return $my_val
```

This returns context undefined error.
Not understanding why.

I also tried this:

```
let $my_val as xs:boolean := (1 = 1)
return $my_val
```

With success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a small type-o.

[`fn:true()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-true) is a function.

You have `fn:true`, so it thinks you trying to reference an element named `true` in the `fn` namespace without a context node to anchor to.

```
let $my_val as xs:boolean := fn:true()
return $my_val
```

Comment: Wow, second pair of eyes well received.